# Athena- extract substring from string - comma delimited

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I want to create Athena view from Athena table.

In table, the column value is "lastname, firstname" so I want to extract these values as 'lastname' and 'firstname' and then need to store it into seperate columns in a view. example- firstname need to be stored into new column- 'first_name' and lastname need to be store into new column - 'last_name'

whats the SQL function which I can use here? I tried split function but then it's giving me an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input strings have a fixed and known number of elements, you can do something like this:

```sql
WITH data(value) AS (
    VALUES ('Aaa,Bbb')
)
SELECT elements[1], elements[2]
FROM (
    SELECT split(value, ',') AS elements
    FROM data
)
```

=>

```
 _col0 | _col1
-------+-------
 Aaa   | Bbb
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

create or replace view "names" as

```
select 
SPLIT_PART("column_name",',', 1) as first_name
, SPLIT_PART("column_name", ',', 2) as last_name
from myTable
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `UNNEST` on the split result:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES   
       ('aaa,bbb'),
       ('aaa1,bbb1')
 ) AS t (str))


SELECT str_col
FROM dataset
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(split(str, ',')) as tmp(str_col)
```

Output:

| str_col |
| --- |
| aaa |
| bbb |
| aaa1 |
| bbb1 |

**UPD**

If you have at least  one comma guaranteed than it is as easy as:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES   
       ('aaa,bbb'),
       ('aaa1,bbb1')
 ) AS t (str))

SELECT splt[1] last_name, splt[2] first_name
FROM
(SELECT split(str, ',') as splt
FROM dataset)
```

Output:

| last_name | first_name |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | bbb |
| aaa1 | bbb1 |

In case you can have varing number of commas but limitied to some number you can use `TRY`:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES   
       ('aaa,bbb'),
       ('aaa1,bbb1,ddd1')
 ) AS t (str))

SELECT splt[1], splt[2], TRY(splt[3])
FROM
(SELECT split(str, ',') as splt
FROM dataset)
```

Output:

| _col0 | _col1 | _col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | bbb |  |
| aaa1 | bbb1 | ddd1 |

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply..

Actually I dont need to store it in a seperate row but in a seperate columns..

Like column1 should have Aaa and column2 should have Bbb.

Comment: @Beginner does string has known number of elements, basically is maximum number of commas known in advance?

Comment: Yes, there is only one comma in each value. 
its like lastname, firstname. so i need to extract lastname and store it into last_name new column and firstname need to be stored into new first_name column